# Adding a Autodesk forge extension

Tags: javascript, html, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Hi I'm trying to add a forge extension in my viewer but I don't know what I have missed.

I followed this article:  https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/loading-external-extensions-forge-viewer

This is my code:

```
 <body>

  <div id="MyViewerDiv"></div>


  <script>
      var myViewerDiv = document.getElementById('MyViewerDiv');
      var viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(myViewerDiv);
      var options = {
          'env' : 'Local',
          'document' : './modelV4/hahahah/4/output.svf',

      };
      Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {
        viewer.start(options.document, options);
      });
      Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExternalExtension(
  'MyExternal.Extension.Id',
  'http://localhost:3000/js/external.js')
  viewer.addEventListener(
  Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, () => {

    viewer.loadExtension('MyExternal.Extension.Id').then(
      function(externalExtension) {

        externalExtension.sayHello('Bob')
      })
  })
  </script>

</body>
```

and this is my path :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With more recent version of Viewer the method described in that article no longer works - you'd need to pass in the extension class/function the directly instead of a link to the extension script:

```
  /**
     * Registers a new extension with the given id.
     *
     * @param {string} extensionId - The string id of the extension.
     * @param {Extension} extension - The Extension-derived class representing the extension.
     * @returns {boolean} - True if the extension was successfully registered.
     * @alias Autodesk.Viewing.ExtensionManager#registerExtension
     */
    function registerExtension(extensionId, extension) {
```

Follow this tutorial [here](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/skeleton) to get started ...

If you'd like to wrap your extension code in another script simply load it with a script tag after the Viewer libraries ...:

```
<script src='https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/viewer3D.min.js'></script>
<script src='path/to/your/extension.js'></script>
```